# Pyinstaller: win32print (pywin32) module not found in .exe

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller, pywin32

I'm trying to get a executable from a Python script with Pyinstaller. In GNU/Linux works fine, but on windows when I open the .exe gives me an error> win32print not found. I tried with "--hidden-import pywin32" without success, and also tried with different versions of Python or Pyinstaller... all dependencies are in a env/ and the others are fine.
Also tried to install pywin32 as windows package.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason why you think the pywin32 is necessary?  What is the full text of the error you are receiving? try providing an [example]

Comment: the error is ModuleNotFound win32print, as far I know is part of pywin32 package... Yes, of course I'll provide it later

Comment: Did you solve this issue?